# Duplicate detail content and action bar items

Tags: android

I developing a sunshine app as mentioned taught in Android nanodegree program. Finished doing the app but I am seeing 2 entries in my detail activity and 2 share menu items.

Below is my github repo.

https://github.com/arupsarkar/sunshine

This is how I am seeing it.

http://discourse-cdn.global.ssl.fastly.net/udacity/uploads/default/optimized/3X/d/9/d98785720464a3da7f3aeb2438e23b63bb1c253e_1_312x500.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

Remove the following from your DetailActivity:

```
    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment, new DetailActivityFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

**Long answer**

You actually adding 2 fragments into your Activity.

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:name="com.kavayah.sunshine.DetailActivityFragment"
```

One in the layout:

```
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
       .add(R.id.fragment, new DetailActivityFragment())
       .commit();
```

Remove the second one. The fragment tag (along with the name attribute) already loaded the fragment in your layout. No need to add another one into it.

**Another note:**

You should create a root activity for all the activities in your application, so that you can share the common menu across them all. No need to repeat after yourself like this everytime you create a new activity (not to mention it will keep everything consistent - no more this-option-works-here-but-not-here situations):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detail, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Extra menu options that is specific to a activity can always be inflated on top of the existing one by calling

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.extra_option, menu);
```

And their behavior can be extended by overriding the `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

Comment: A disagree with EE66 (sorry, not enough reputation to comment on others' comment - :P ).

Again. It's all about reusability and portability. Fragment can be included in any other layouts. Separating its menu option from itself is not very wise. It might work fine in this case, but I think that is not a good practice to follow.